# Can't connect to admin interface of Asus EA-N66

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-extender

I have recently setup a new router and was trying to use a "second hand" [ASUS EA-N66](https://www.asus.com/Networking/EAN66/) as range extender.

I factory reset it, and then proceeded to configure it, and the configuration was successful as I am now navigating through it being connected via LAN cable.

The wifi also works, I can connect with my smartphone and use internet.

The problem is that, after the configuration, I cannot access the web interface anymore.

Before configuring it, I could access through http://10.0.0.1, and after the configuration it was accessible, but only for a while, through http://www.asusnetwork.net

I have also checked on the main router, and tried connecting to the IP address which its DHCP server assigned to it, but that didn't work either.

How can I get access to the web interface again, short of factory resetting it again?

I didn't change any other configuration option in the extender.

Comment: have you tried https with the IP address?

Comment: Yes, but no effect, also I didn't change those options, so I'd think https wouldn't be available at all.

Comment: Make sure you try Internet Explorer to access. Older routers often demanded this. Hopefully the issue is not Java.

Comment: I must admit I didn't think about this solution, mainly because when it worked, it did so with the latest chrome; anyway I'll try it as soon as I'm back home after work